# Editing normals for a cylinder

Tags: modeling, normals, blend4web

I have a cylinder completely smoothed like the following (the purple lines are the **vertex normals**):

[image]

My final goal is to reach the result below:

[image]

I'm using the Blender4Web Addons, but I can't still achieve the target. I can easily have the situation below:

[image]

---

The problem is creating the right angle for the vertex normals along the curve... How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to copy the normal position, from a duplicate of the mesh, without rim faces. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Nice one!! Do you think this is the fastest way possible? Or using different addons/methods (just saying, don't know if it exist something related to editing normals except blender4web) the result could be quicker?

Comment: I don't know really. I don't edit normals very often, so wasn't looking for the fastest possible way. When I want to get certain look in OpenGL, I usually use edge split modifier.